# sonoma modal apps only with windows of same app

Tags: macos

How do I get side-by-side apps in macOS sonoma again?

I used to have YouTube open at the same time as other apps.

Very annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have accidentally turned on [Stage Manager](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213315). From Apple documentation:

> Stage Manager shows the app you're currently using in the center of the screen. Other apps you're using appear as thumbnails on the side.

This means that only apps from the same group are allowed to occupy the screen at the same time.

You can turn it off from Control Center:

[image]

Comment: ah many thankssss

Answer (score 1):

macOS Sonoma did not change the side by side zoom (which Apple calls Split View)

I activate by long pressing or leaving your mouse for ~1s on the green / maximize control in the window bar:

[image: macOS window manager - side by side control]

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-apps-in-split-view-mchl4fbe2921/mac

Comment: thats not what I want, I want to keep all the windows as the are not disappear when switching app

Comment: @Nikos I fail to understand what you want. What do you mean by "keep all the windows as the(y?) are not disappear when switching app"? Do you just want to have two windows on the desktop?